# MongoDB / MongoEngine - Query for Item in List

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I have a series of MongoDB documents like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("53992c7d02b8756437f81cba"),
 "account_id" : ObjectId("5397929402b8751ae8a32349"),
 "event_history" : [ 
                     [ 0, ISODate("2014-06-12T04:28:45.684Z") ],
                     [ 0, ISODate("2014-06-11T04:28:45.684Z") ],
                     [ 1, ISODate("2014-05-12T04:28:45.684Z") ] 
                   ],
 "status" : 1
}
```

Is it possible to return the `event_history`'s which have a `0` as the first element (in MongoEngine)?

I want to get this:

```
[ 0, ISODate("2014-06-12T04:28:45.684Z") ],
[ 0, ISODate("2014-06-11T04:28:45.684Z") ],
```

Here's the query I tried, but it doesn't work:

`Record.objects(id=ObjectId("53992c7d02b8756437f81cba"), event_history__in=[0])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Good question. There are a few things here that make this not straightforward.

The first mention to give is the nested arrays/lists thing being not standard django fair, but you could dive into the [`__raw__`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries) syntax offered by MongoEngine as this does need to be a little more MongoDB specific.

That said, even so, the type of filtering that you want to do here is even out of scope for a standard MongoDB `.find()` type of query, as you are expecting to match multiple inner array members and then "filter" the returned members in the result.

This is actually quite tricky for not only the nested arrays but also the sort of thing that can be done only using the aggregation framework. Which despite any clear documentation on this, you can get at with MongoEngine by accessing the "raw" pymongo driver functions for the collection using the `._get_collection()` method on your class.

Commented for explaination:

```
Record._get_collection().aggregate([
    # Match only those documents that would meet the condition
    { "$match": { 
        "event_history": { 
            "$elemMatch": { 
                "$elemMatch": {"$in": [0] }
            }
        }
    }},

    # Unwind the event history array, top level
    { "$unwind": "$event_history" },

    # Make a copy of the inner array
    { "$project": {
        "account_id": 1,
        "event_history": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "copy": "$event_history"
    }},

    # Unwind that copy
    { "$unwind": "$copy" },

    # Match the numeric 0 elements only, filters non-matches
    { "$match": { "copy": 0 } },

    # Group back to the original document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "account_id": { "$first": "$account_id" },
        "event_history": { "$push": "$event_history" },
        "status": { "$first": "$status" }
    }}
])
```

If there was more than one numeric value in there that could be 0 then you need to know it's the first one. So a little more involved:

```
Record._get_collection().aggregate([
    # Match only those documents that would meet the condition
    { "$match": { 
        "event_history": { 
            "$elemMatch": { 
                "$elemMatch": {"$in": [0] }
            }
        }
    }},

    # Unwind the event history array, top level
    { "$unwind": "$event_history" },

    # Make a copy of the inner array
    { "$project": {
        "account_id": 1,
        "event_history": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "copy": "$event_history"
    }},

    # Unwind that copy
    { "$unwind": "$copy" },

    # Group back the document keeping the "first" inner element only
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "account_id": "$account_id",
            "event_history": "$event_history",
            "status": "$status"
        },
        "copy": { "$first": "$copy" }
    }},

    # Match only where 0 to filter
    { "$match": { "copy": 0 } },

    # Group back to the original document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "account_id": { "$first": "$_id.account_id" },
        "event_history": { "$push": "$_id.event_history" },
        "status": { "$first": "$status" }
    }}
])
```

And the result in each case:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53992c7d02b8756437f81cba"),
    "account_id" : ObjectId("5397929402b8751ae8a32349"),
    "event_history" : [
            [ 0, ISODate("2014-06-11T04:28:45.684Z") ],
            [ 0, ISODate("2014-06-12T04:28:45.684Z") ]
    ],
    "status": 1
}
```

So yes the process looks a little involved and is not a straightforward as you might think. But thankfully there is a way to access the raw collection methods and use [aggregate](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) to solve this.